# Safari only firing onChange once after initial onKeyDown in text input

Tags: reactjs, safari, onchange

I have an input field in my react component that has an `onChange()` that calls a function I wrote. The `onKeyDown()` also calls this function, but only in limited cases.

But my `onChange()` only gets called once in Safari on input changes, which does not update my input field as I expect. In Chrome my `onChange()` is called every time there is a change in my input from the user and updates the input field as I expect.

Has anyone run into this? And found a solution?

I've tried replacing `onChange()` with `onInput()`, but then read that react's `onChange()` is basically javascript's `onInput()`.

**Update:** I found that my problem is that I define my input that I pass as a prop to another component in my render function. My `onChange()` on that input contains a `setState()`, which rerenders my component and (I think) unregisters my `onChange()`. But again, this only happens in Safari - works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

**Update2:** Turns out it was a css webkit flag that wasn't a problem in all the other browsers, but was a problem in safari. I unset it and it worked (in case anyone else runs into this in the future).

Comment: can you elaborate more on CSS issue?

Comment: What's the CSS webkit flag that was causing the issue?

Comment: Sorry folks just seeing this comments. I left the role where I had this issue a while ago so I don’t have access to that code base and I don’t remember which flag it was unfortunately. But I do remember I just opened the console in safari and just started unselecting WebKit flags until my issue went away. Sorry I can’t be more help after all this time.

Comment: It's the `user-select` property. It'll be probably `none`, change it to `auto`.